# Consume OData Service in SAP Build Prototypes

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

​When we are creating prototypes on ​​[Build](https://www.build.me/) we can consume OData service from Excel​.

My doubt is if we can consume OData Gateway Service on Build? If it's possible, how can I do it?

Comment: Voting to close this question since SAP [announced to abandon SAP Build](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/02/04/sap-build-product-sunset/). There won't be any new features added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible. All you can do is import the metadata as Edmx file and fill the mock data corresponding to that metadata.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option;

> You can also import objects from EDMX file (OData)

You can also try SAP Cloud Platform WebIDE. You can easily create a destination using your OData Gateway service and consume it via a template app.